# Connecting to remote SQL Server through PHP on Mac OS

Tags: php, sql-server, driver

Trying to connect to a remote SQL Server (2008) on local network through a PHP (5.6.7) script running with MAMP on Mac OS Yosemite. I am reading a lot of conflicting information online. I am wondering what the best practices are here and necessary first steps. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: [Everything is in the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mssql.php)

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to connect using the FreeTDS driver. There are good instructions available here:

http://www.acloudtree.com/how-to-install-freetds-and-unixodbc-on-osx-using-homebrew-for-use-with-ruby-php-and-perl/

Please reply if you have any issues, it can be a tricky setup.

Comment: Thanks so much. Yes indeed it was a bit tricky but successfully installed unixodbc. I can now connect to remote sql servers through the terminal services like 'isql'. However, I can't seem to figure out how to enable the driver in php. I don't see the odbc.so extension file in the extensions folder, where I think it should be (then enabled in .ini file). Any ideas?

Comment: How are you trying to connect via PHP? mssql_connect() or something else?